# AWS Amplify and Next.JS with GraphQL Server Error No current user from getStaticPaths

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm having trouble accessing data from Amplify's API Graphql, and it keeps returning

```
Server Error
Error: No current user
```

I've been following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/13nYLmjZ0Ys?t=2292

I know I'm signed into Amplify because if I go into different pages, I can grab user Auth and I can even display the SignOut button. But for whatever reason, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { listActivations, getActivation } from "../../graphql/queries";

const Activation = ({ activation }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return <div>{activation.title}</div>;
};
export default Activation;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  console.log("static paths");
  const activationData = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: listActivations,
  });
  console.log("activationData", activationData);
  const paths = activationData.data.listActivations.items.map((activation) => ({
    params: { id: activation.id },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const SSR = withSSRContext(); // added SSR, but still getting error
  console.log("static props");
  const { id } = params;
  const activationData = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: getActivation,
    variables: { id },
  });
  return {
    props: {
      activation: activationData.data.getActivation,
    },
  };
}
```

The console log `static paths` appears, and then after that, I get errors.

Do you think it has anything to do with my GraphQL schema?

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "username" }]) {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  userType: UserType
}

type Activation
  @model
  @key(
    name: "activationsByStudentId"
    fields: ["student"]
    queryField: "activationsByStudentId"
  )
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
      { allow: owner }
      {
        allow: owner
        ownerField: "studentId"
        operations: [create, update, delete]
      }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  studentId: ID!
  title: String!
  student: Student @connection(fields: ["studentId"])
  teachers: [TeachersActivations] @connection(name: "ActivationTeachers")
}
```

Edit: I've also added User model to see if this could be a cause too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amplify. Anyway, `getStaticProps` is used with static generation, ie. it is called at build time. You can be signed into Amplify at runtime, however, it won't affect any static data fetching.

Comment: @Riwen sure, but what does that mean about "No current user"? I'm even following the tutorial from Amplify itself: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/next?sc_icampaign=next-start&sc_ichannel=choose-integration#api-with-incremental-static-site-generation-ssg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still, I couldn't figure out the issue why this can't work, so I decided to move my query into client-side

```
const [activation, setActivation] = useState(null);

const router = useRouter();
const { aid } = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
  if (!aid) return;

  async function activationDataFromClient() {
    try {
      const getActivationData = await API.graphql({
        query: getActivation,
        variables: {
          id: aid,
        },
      });

      setActivation(getActivationData.data.getActivation);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error fetching activation data: ", err);
    }
  }
  activationDataFromClient();
}, [aid]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` are called during build time, and on the server when `fallback` is equal to `true`, you need to configure Amplify for SSR (Server-Side Rendering). Make sure to take a look at [SSR Support for AWS Amplify JavaScript Libraries](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/ssr-support-for-aws-amplify-javascript-libraries/).

The solution: first, configure Amplify for SSR:

```
Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });
```

Then you need to use `withSSRContext`, and add the the `authMode` parameter. As quoted from the link above:

> For example, take an AppSync GraphQL API that is backed by an identity provider such as Amazon Cognito User pools, Okto, or Auth0. Some GraphQL types may require a user to be authenticated to perform certain requests. Using the API class, the user identity will now automatically be configured and passed into the API request headers:

```
const SSR = withSSRContext();
const activationData = await SSR.API.graphql({
  query: listActivations,
  authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
});
```

Comment: Oops, I actually added that on my codebase, I just didn't update it on my question. But even with SSR, I'm getting the issue

Comment: Please make sure to update the code in the question.

Comment: Do you configure Amplify for SSR, ie. `Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });`?

Comment: Yeah I have it in my `_app.js`

Comment: Arg, I still don't get it, this doesn't work either. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing the `authMode` to `'API_KEY'` enabled it to work for me. See example below:

```
export async function getStaticPaths(context) {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  const { data } = await SSR.API.graphql({ 
    query: listArticles,
    authMode: 'API_KEY' 
  });
  const paths = data.listArticles.items.map((article) => ({
    params: { id: article.id },
  }));
  
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
  
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const SSR = withSSRContext();
  const { data } = await SSR.API.graphql({
    query: getArticle,
    variables: {
      id: params.id,
    },
    authMode: 'API_KEY' 
  });
  
  return {
    props: { 
      article: data.getArticle
    }
  }
}
```